# samba4's ldbsearch complains about authentication for basic searches

Tags: samba, ldap, samba4

So I understand the concept of binding to a LDAP server of any kind and performing either authenticated or anonymous queries.

And my goal is to get the full `dn=...dc=example,dc=com` for a specific user.

And I know I've set up my samba4 as a AD controller in a way that it shouldn't allow anonymous queries/bindings.

What surprises me is that `ldbsearch` differs from `ldapsearch` (OpenLDAP's client application) in a way that, it doesn't support authentication?

So my basic query looks like:

```
# ldbsearch -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -b "DC=example,DC=com" "(CN=usernameHere)"
search error - 00002020: Operation unavailable without authentication
```

Now this is done on the AD controller, and I'm sure you could point out to the `.db` file containing all the accounts and what not, but I would prefer to be able to do this remotely via `smb://` or `ldap://`.

I've also tried `smb://` just for the sake of it:

```
Unable to find backend for 'smb://127.0.0.1' - do you need to set LDB_MODULES_PATH?
```

Further more, I've tried using kerberos tickets in order to perhaps see if `ldbsearch` could pick that up and use that as authentication:

```
# kinit administrator@example.com
Password for administrator@example.com: 
Warning: Your password will expire in 26 days on Wed 06 Jul 2016 09:27:36 PM CEST
```

`ldbsearch` still gives me the exact same error.
So how do you go about perfoming searches on your domain with `samba4`?

I should add that the following command works:

```
# ldbsearch -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -s base -b "" defaultNamingContext

# record 1
dn: 
defaultNamingContext: DC=example,DC=com

# returned 1 records
# 1 entries
# 0 referrals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `-U` option with the right username, and optionally the password:

```
ldbsearch -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -s sub -b 'DC=example,DC=com' -U Administrator%YourPassword
```

or, to not leave the password in the command history, use the `-A` option with a file containing the username and password:

```
ldbsearch -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -s sub -b 'DC=example,DC=com' -A My_Auth_File
```

The file "My_Auth_File" would contain for example:

```
username=Administrator
password=My-Admin-password
```

Unfortunately, `man ldbsearch` doesn't show all possible options. `ldbsearch --usage` shows many more:

> ldbsearch --usage
>
> Usage: [-?viraSNPeV] [-?|--help] [--usage]
> [-H|--url=URL] [-b|--basedn=DN] [-e|--editor=PROGRAM]
> [-s|--scope=SCOPE] [-v|--verbose] [--trace] [-i|--interactive]
> [-r|--recursive] [--modules-path=PATH] [--num-searches=INT] [--num-records=INT] [-a|--all] [--nosync] [-S|--sorted] [-o=OPTION]
> [--controls=STRING] [--show-binary]
> [--paged] [--show-deleted] [--show-recycled] [--show-deactivated-link] [--reveal] [--relax] [--cross-ncs]
> [--extended-dn] [-d|--debuglevel=DEBUGLEVEL]
> [--debug-stderr] [-s|--configfile=CONFIGFILE] [--option=name=value] [-l|--log-basename=LOGFILEBASE] [--leak-report]
> [--leak-report-full]
> [-U|--user=[DOMAIN/]USERNAME[%PASSWORD]] [-N|--no-pass] [--password=STRING] [-A|--authentication-file=FILE]
> [-P|--machine-pass] [--simple-bind-dn=STRING]
> [-k|--kerberos=STRING] [--krb5-ccache=STRING] [-S|--sign] [-e|--encrypt] [-R|--name-resolve=NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER]
> [-O|--socket-options=SOCKETOPTIONS]

And `ldbsearch --help` shows them in a much more readable way with a short description.

(this is with Samba 4.9.5 on Debian 10.11)

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I know it's been five years since I've posted this and I rarely use Active Directory any more. So without even questioning this, I will assume that you as a strange on the internet have tested this and it works - there for I'll mark your answer as correct : )

Comment: @Torxed: I also use AD as rarely as possible ... :-) but I needed it yesterday, so came across this old post when I also had trouble with that.